# Having trouble with showing this cannot be a theorem in incidence geometry.

Tags: geometry

Consider the following statement:
If $l$ and $m$ are any two distinct lines, then there exists a point $P$ that does not lie on either $l$ or $m$.

(a) Show that this cannot be a theorem in incidence geometry.

(b) Prove that the above statement is true in any projective plane.

I have no idea on what I can do to solve this problem. I do know the incidence axioms, but how can I use them to disprove this?

Answer (score 2):

To show that something cannot be a theorem in incidence geometry, it suffices to exhibit a model in which all the axioms of incidence geometry hold but the "theorem" does not.  So you need to find a model of incidence geometry with two distinct lines $l$ and $m$ such that all points lie on either $l$ or $m$ (or both).  Can you find such a model?